# Перевод hex-строки в байты

Tags: c++, c

Есть некая строка (обязательно с четным кол-вом символов), например "4AABC1FD".
Её нужно представить в виде шестнадцатеричных байт, например "\x4A\xAB\xC1\xFD".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Вполне возможно стандартными средствами C++.

```
std::string str_hex = "4AABC1FD";
uint32_t hx = std::stol(str_hex,nullptr,16);
std::cout << std::hex << hx << std::endl;
```

Для представления массивом символов можно использовать следующую строку:

```
char *out = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hx);
```

Последовательность байт (прямая или обратная) будет определяться архитектурой процессора.

Comment: Это не совсем о, что нужно, я бы хотел это сделать `char source[] = "4AABC1FD";` => `char out = "\x4A\xAB\xC1\xFD";`

Comment: @clay Т.е. Вам нужно просто вставить через каждые два символа `\x`?

Comment: Черт, походу я жестко протупливаю. Таким образом можно будет исползовать эту строку как последовательность *именно* байт, а не символов?

Comment: @clay Так а Вы думаете, что то, что я привел в ответе не является последовательностью байт? число hx в моем ответе и есть последовательность 4-х байт. Посмотрите по адресу &hx и увидите свои числа. В зависимости от архитектуры процессора эти байты будут либо в прямом, либо в обратном порядке.

Comment: Окей, начинаю понимать:  `std::string str_hex = "44434241";
 uint32_t hx = std::stol(str_hex, nullptr, 16);
 char *out = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hx);
 std::cout << out << std::endl;` выводит ABCD и какой-то мусор в конце, как от него избаиться?

Comment: @clay out - это указатель. Вы пытаетесь вывести на экран область памяти. Это не строка, которая оканчивается нулем. Хотите, можете закрыть ее нулем.

Comment: >в виде шестнадцатеричных байт

И никого не покоробила эта формулировка.